# why list works in this way of python?

Tags: python, list

wierd problem here, line 6 and line 11, is wierd, I can't figure it out why?

```
1 l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
2 
3 l2 = [[]] * 3
4 for i in xrange(0, len(l1)):
5     l2[i%len(l1)].extend(l1[i]) # look! not [li[i]] here
6 print 'l2: ', l2  # problem is here
7 
8 l3 = [[]] * 3
9 for i in xrange(0, len(l1)):
10     l3[i%len(l1)].extend([l1[i]]) 
11 print 'l3: ', l3
12 
13 l4 = [[]] * 3
14 for i in xrange(0, len(l1)):
15     if l4[i%len(l1)] == []:
16         l4[i%len(l1)] = [l1[i]]
17     else:
18         l4[i%len(l1)].extend([l1[i]])
19 print 'l4: ', l4
```

output blow:

```
l2:  [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
l3:  [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
l4:  [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

Someone can point out why? Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: This happens because `l2 = [[]] * 3` creates a list that contains *three copies* of the same list: if you append to one, you append to all of them. Try `[[] for _ in range(3)]` instead. (I *know* this is a duplicate of other StackOverflow questions, just have to find them).

Comment: This is described under *mutable sequences* [in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#index-20). Read the part that contains *often haunts new Python programmers*.

Comment: More generally to what David said: `list * int` does *not* duplicate (shallow or otherwise) the source elements.

Comment: Thanks to David Robinson for the simple and clear explantation. But why line5 worked the same way as line10?

Comment: Obviously some people with more motivation than myself were willing to read through your code and figure out your question, but in general you will be more likely to get a good response if you **provide some more details**. Nineteen lines of uncommented code with all the variables named similarly isn't very conducive to understanding what you're looking for. In the future, I suggest describing at a high level what the code is supposed to do, and then explain how the output is different from what you expect. You will be more likely to get responses that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 5 works the same way as line 10, because a string is also a sequence of characters.  So for example:

```
list('abc') == ['a', 'b', 'c']
list('a')   == ['a']
```

In this case, `.extend('a')` works because the string `'a'` is considered as a sequence of one character, which is `'a'` again.  But try to compare `.extend('abc')` and `.extend(['abc'])` to see that they are not identical.  (The first one gives slightly unexpected results, so I wouldn't recommend using it.)

Comment: Special thanks to Armin Rigo and David Robinson. For you two simple and clear explantation.

Answer (score 4):

Because multiplying a list by an int creates a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy#Deep_copy), not a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy#Shallow_copy).

Python doesn't make deep copies for most things unless you explicitly tell it to do so due to the way deep copies work with objects, which can make them copy too much stuff, or that can end up having issues with self-references.

Python has a way of dealing with that in [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), however, for user-defined classes, you need to implement that method yourself. To avoid all that trouble, when copying mutable objects (such as lists) implicitly like in your example, shallow copies are made.

Comment: Thanks to David Robinson for the simple and clear explantation. But why line5 worked the same way as line10?

Answer (score 0):

What you expect, and for which some intermediate to experienced programmers may still fall from time to time, is that

```
l = [some_object] * 3
```

creates *copies* of `some_object`. In python, however, this will just duplicate the references to that object, so you have in fact the very same object three times in one list. As lists are mutable, changing the object through one reference changes also what you see through the other references.

If you want to create different objects, as already mentioned in the comments, you have to do it like this:

```
[create_some_object for _ in range(3)]
```

In case of lists, it's straightforwardly: `[ [] for _ in range(3)]`.

In some cases, one does not notice the difference, namely when dealing with immutable objects, such as tuples, strings, integers or NoneType. These cannot be changed, only be replaced, thus it doesn't matter how many references to one object exist, because if one wants to change the object in one place, one has to reconstruct a new one and replace that reference. The other references keep pointing to the same object and, thus, do not change.